# Set function as dict value in Python and pass arguments

Tags: python

I want to create something like a "Switch case" object in Python, i'm using a dict and I want it to call a function when the key is used in my code.

This is the code

```
def main():
    switch = {
        1: incSearch(),
        2: bisec()
    }  
    switch.get(input(), lambda: print('Invalid option'))
```

The trouble cames that every time I run my script, it automatically executes the first method without letting the user input

Comment: You're calling the function, you just forgot to remove the `()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the function's name without calling it when storing in a dictionary:

```
switch = {
    1: incSearch,
    2: bisec
}
```

You should also call the function after getting it from the dict:

```
switch.get(input(), lambda: print('Invalid option'))()
```

Comment: I ended up using it like that, I'm using functions name, but now how do I pass the parameters to the function?, I can't find a decent way to do that.

Comment: You can add parameters that will be sent to every function in the last parentheses.